# H2 database - CSVREAD/CSVWRITE - what is the option name for field enclosure?

Tags: csv, h2

I am using H2 database in my java application. I am using `CSVWRITE` command to write the data from DB to a file. The only issue is that the values written to the file are enclosed with double quotes. A record is shown below for instance:

```
"TN"|"8903555"|"2012-01-08 23:20:27.0"|"Hello"|"Postpaid"|"TN2011120810070811"
```

I want the above line to be exported without double quotes, like the below one:

```
TN|8903555|2012-01-08 23:20:27.0|Hello|Postpaid|TN2011120810070811
```

So what is the option name in `CSVWRITE` command that I can use for this. Below is the command that I am using for exporting the data to a file:

```
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/admin/Documents/abc.txt', 'SELECT * FROM TEST0 WHERE IN_DATE >= ''2012-01-08 00:00:00'' AND IN_DATE < ''2012-01-09 00:00:00''', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=|');
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

```
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/admin/Documents/abc.txt',
    'SELECT * FROM TEST0 WHERE IN_DATE >= ''2012-01-08 00:00:00'' 
    AND IN_DATE < ''2012-01-09 00:00:00''', 
    'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=| fieldDelimiter=');
```

The fieldDelimiter doesn't need to be specified at the end. If you want a space as a field delimiter, you need to escape it using a backslash: `'...  fieldDelimiter=\ '`